# How recreate blank table automatically in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

So I'm just getting into Excel and I want to learn more about it so please bear with me.

Currently I have a working timesheet that does what I want. Well, not everything...what I want to do is use it to keep a record of weeks and such. So my question; is there a way to automatically create an exactly similar table but empty? No dates or times, all blank and waiting to be filled in but with the formulas still intact so that all I have to do is fill in the dates and time and it automatically calculates everything. What I would love is to automatically create a new table when I hit enter into a new row but at this point I'm just wondering how I'd copy this table so that it's blank and ready to be filled in. Any advice or help is appreciated!

Comment: Use a template worksheet or template workbook.

Comment: Or record the process with a macro recorder, tidy up, then add a line in to add a worksheet so a new worksheet is being worked with, then tie that macro to a button. Might even work with recording simply copying the template sheet and pasting as a new sheet in the same workbook. You'd have to check whether formulas ended up pointing back to original or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can record a macro by going into Developer > Record Macro.
Then you go into Insert table and you insert a new table.
Finally you go back to developer and you stop registering the macro.

You can just insert a button by going into Developer Insert Button and then assign to that button the macro that you have just created. By clicking on that button you will have a new table every time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works great but I ran into an issue where I created a macro that would make a new table but also shift the previous one over so that it isn't in the way. When I shift the table it doesn't keep the adjustments I made to the columns...Otherwise than that it works exactly how I want it